# Is it possible to access current file name?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to access current file name in Rust by

```
// main.rs
fn main() {
    println!("filename: {}", FILE_NAME);
}
```

?

(This program should print `filename: main.rs`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [std::file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.file.html) macro to get the current source filename at the compile time.

```
let this_file = file!();
```

If you want to remove the path from the returned filename, you can construct a `Path` with it and call the `file_name` method.

```
let filename_only = Path::new(this_file).file_name().and_then(|s| s.to_str()).unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03f52631f6fc4080fe91764f78a7db26)